# Regex extractor in JMeter to match text with multiple line breaks

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

I try to use `Regular Expression Extractor` in JMeter to match multiple lines with line breaks. It is a JSON formatted text, which is between `textarea` tags. I used this matcher in expression: `((.|\n|\r)*)` , but got `StackOverflowError`.

> Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null    at
> org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source)
> ~[oro-2.0.8.jar:?]

Comment: A Java way to make `.` match line breaks is by using the `s` flag, `(?s).*`. Or `(?s:.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following regular expression:

```
(?s)<textarea>(.+?)</textarea>
```

[image]

More information: [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

If you're not too comfortable with regular expressions you can consider switching to [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), it's sufficient to supply "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between